# How do I convert between .pbp and .iso?

Tags: iso, convert, emulation

I have some homebrew PSP games in eboot pbp format, and I would like to convert these to .iso format for RetroPie.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing to do if you want to change from .pbp is to change the extension name to .iso .

Comment: Are you certain that the formats are identical?

Comment: yes just try it out with a pseudo file

Comment: I agree. My experience shows that most images differ only in file name extension. That is not true %100 of the time, but try that first.